# viewWithTag doesn't work for tags set in XIB file

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm setting up 8 buttons in my nib file (buttons for digits 1..8) and I don't want to create 8 IBOutlets, so instead in the properties I set up the tag to 1,2,3...,8, and in my code I try to get the button with:

```
UIButton* buttonToMove = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:digitToMove];
```

This doesn't work though. Any idea what am I doing wrong? All other views in my nib file have their tags set as default (0).

Comment: What does “doesn't work” mean?  Does each call to `viewWithTag:` return `nil`?  Or something else?  In what method are you calling `viewWithTag:`?  Show us the context around that call.

Comment: Check `self.view`. Is it pointing to `nil`? Is it pointing to a view that is in the same hierarchy as your button?

Comment: Sorry guys it seems my problem was somewhere else and in fact the function works fine! My mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get some other instance (not a button) because you have multiple subviews with a tag of 1. `viewWithTag:` just gets and returns the first one it finds. It's also possible that the view isn't loaded / added as a subview for some reason when you make the request.

Consider using an `IBOutletCollection` instead.